# Two Click Functions with Parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a specific time checkbox and upon click I need the days of the week to drop down with a checkbox. Once the user clicks that checkbox the [From - To] appears.

The thing is I have multiple of these going down and need to only display for the certain one I clicked.

So far I only have it set it for Monday but I cant get the from-to to appear on the first one.

```
<div class="specificHolder">

      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
         Specific Time<input type="checkbox" class="specificTime">
       </div>
      </div>

          <div class="specific_on" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                Monday<input type="checkbox" class="monday">
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>

  <div class="specificHolder">

      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
         Specific Time<input type="checkbox" class="specificTime">
       </div>
      </div>

          <div class="specific_on" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                Monday<input type="checkbox" class="monday">
                  <div class="monday_to_from" style="display:none">
                    <input type="text" value="From">
                    <input type="text" value="To">
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

```
$('.specificTime').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.specificHolder').find('.specific_on').toggle('slow');
});

$('.monday').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('.specificHolder').find('.monday_to_from').toggle('slow');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y1b8fr20/

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Using `toggle()` between more than one trigger creates a confusing behavior. This update separates the sliding of up and down and listens for the change event instead of the click event for more control between `.monday` checkboxes. Now it will behave as follows:

- The `to from` boxes only appears when a `.monday` checkbox is checked
- If a `.monday` checkbox is unchecked, the `.to from` boxes will slideUp.
- If either `.monday` is checked, `fromto` stays.
- `fromto` will only slideUp if both `.monday`s are unchecked

---

You have only one `from to` input so this is sufficient:

```
   $('.monday').on('change', function() {

  if ($('.monday').is(':checked')) {

    $('.monday_to_from').slideDown('slow');

  } else {

    $('.monday_to_from').slideUp('slow');
  }
});
```

Move this out of the influence of the second set of checkboxes:

```
<div class="monday_to_from" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="From">
  <input type="text" value="To">
</div>
```

### Demo

```js
$('.specificTime').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.specificHolder').find('.specific_on').toggle('slow');
});

$('.monday').on('change', function() {

  if ($('.monday').is(':checked')) {

    $('.monday_to_from').slideDown('slow');
    
  } else {
  
    $('.monday_to_from').slideUp('slow');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="specificHolder">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      Specific Time<input type="checkbox" class="specificTime">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="specific_on" style="display:none">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Monday<input type="checkbox" class="monday">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="specificHolder">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      Specific Time<input type="checkbox" class="specificTime">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="specific_on" style="display:none">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Monday<input type="checkbox" class="monday">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="monday_to_from" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="From">
  <input type="text" value="To">
</div>
```

Comment: I literally just solved my own question, didnt notice I only had the to_from in one. But a side question, now since they both hold a value does that mean that from_to belongs to the Monday I've clicked on?

Comment: I want to submit a form after and each one of these will be a form but I need the corresponding from_to

Comment: No, it is now a sibling of both `.specificHolder` Is there a reason why you can't just have 2 from to? Or does Monday only get one event?

Comment: Well this would be wrapped in a foreach statement but as a test on jsfiddle I just copied them both to act as two